# Flutter call to Cloud function is resolving in DEADLINE_EXCEEDED cloud function exception

Tags: javascript, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I have a problem with calling a cloud function from Flutter. In this Cloud Function I am doing some different things, like safe search checking an image via ML-Vision ImageAnnotatorClient, adding a document to Firestore or updating metadata for a Storage file. Usually all this is working fine, but nearly every time when a device is the first time calling this function after some time, it fails with the CloudFunctionException DEADLINE_EXCEEDED. In every other try it is working just fine without any issue. Does someone has an idea what could cause it?

I read that there is a 'cold start' of a function, which is causing the function to taking a much longer time to execute. But still, it is always executed in less than 10seconds, so a timeout does not seem to be an issue here.

This is how I call the Flutter Cloud Function

```
final HttpsCallable callable = _cloudFunctions.getHttpsCallable(
  functionName: 'function',
);

dynamic resp = await callable.call({'prop1': prop1String, 'prop2': prop2String});
```

This is the content of the Cloud Function

```
exports.function = functions.https.onCall(async (req, context) => {
    if (!context.auth) return {status: 'ERROR', code: 401, body: 'Not signed in'};

    const [result] = await client.safeSearchDetection(req.url);
    const detections = result.safeSearchAnnotation;
    if (detections) {
        if (detections.adult === 'VERY_LIKELY') {
            const storage = new Storage();
            await storage
                .bucket('xxx.appspot.com/')
                .file(req.filename)
                .delete();
            return {status: 'ERROR', code: 400, body: 'NSFW'};
        }
    }

    return refs.add({
        'prop1': req.prop2,
        'prop2': req.prop1
    })
        .then(async () => {
            const images = [];
            const query = await refs
                .where('prop1', '==', req.prop1)
                .get();
            query.forEach((document) => images.push(document));
            if (images.length > 0) {
                const docRef = refs.doc(images[0].id);
                const filename = images[0['_fieldsProto']['filename']['stringValue'];
                const storage = new Storage();
                await storage
                    .bucket('xxx.appspot.com/')
                    .file(filename)
                    .setMetadata({metadata: {receiver: req.uid}});
                docRef.update({'receiver': req.uid, 'receivedTimestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
                return {status: 'OK', code: 200, body: images[0]};
            } else {
                return {status: 'OK', code: 200, body: null};
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            return {status: 'ERROR', code: 500, body: 'failed to create ref in firestore'};
        });
});
```

There error occurs in the Flutter code, when calling the callable.

Comment: Have you done a search for "Firestore DEADLINE_EXCEEDED" to find out what the typical causes are?

Comment: Yes I did this. I can not see why it is failing, especially because it is only failing after the first execution.

Comment: Without your code, we can't see either.  Please edit the question to show the code, and explain exactly which part of it causes the error.

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.exceptions#deadlineexceedederror) on the firebase admin module, which is what you are likely using, this error happens when if the caller sets a deadline that is shorter than the method’s default deadline and the request did not finish within the deadline. This is likely to be what is happening but in order to figure out for sure, we need to take a look at what you code is doing, can you share your cloud function's code?

Comment: Hi DougStevenson & ralemos, I added my code to the post.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out what call is generating this error, but there are a couple of things that you can do to workaround that.

- Increase the memory and timeout of your function.

Your function is currently running on default settings, which is 128MB of memory and 60s before timeout. You can change that to up to 2GB and 540s, note that this will have an impact on your billing. You can implement that by doing the following:

```
const runtimeOpts = {
    timeoutSeconds: 300,
    memory: '1GB'
}
exports.function = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onCall(...)
```

Also here is a [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_runtime_options) with more details on that.

- Increase the timeout of your Firestore calls

You can add the following code to your firestore initialization, replacing `YOUR_NUMBER_HERE`, to increase the time before timeout (The default is 60000 or 1 minute), this is also likely to have impacts on your billing:

```
const firestore = new Firestore({
      clientConfig: {
        interfaces: {
          'google.firestore.v1.Firestore': {
              methods: {
                RunQuery: {
                  timeout_millis: YOUR_NUMBER_HERE
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
```

Let me know if this solved the issue.

Comment: Hi @ralemos , sorry for the late response. I upvoted your answer because it was useful, I did the recommend things you said. But this error still occurs and it seems that its only occur on Android devices. I have really no idea why this happens and users start complaining about this..

Comment: That's odd, I would suggest that in that case you reach out to Google Cloud's Paid Support [here](https://cloud.google.com/support), or for you to submit a bug report on their issue tracker system [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=0), that way, if it is a bug on specific devices/OS they might be able to solve it.